# JQuery to add "scrolling" buttons and to refresh the main page when there is new data available?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to do the following:

- 1 -  Update `index.html` with the content from `output.html` using jquery (only update when the data is different, if possible find a way to update the parts that have changed?
- 2 -  Introduce two buttons in the header for "Left" and "Right" to be able to scroll left and right across the table.

I've had a lot of attempts to get it working but I can't get it going, below is a copy of my attempted step 1 (update `index.html` with new content from `output.html`

#### Main HTML (index.html) trying to call Secondary HTML (output.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Website</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        <!-- @import url("nstyle.css");
        -->
    </style>
    <script>
        update_content()
         $(document).ready(function (e) {
            var refresher = setInterval("update_content();", 250);
        })
        function update_content() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "testoutput.html",
                timeout: 10000,
                cache: false,
            })
                .done(function (page_html) {
                    var currentDoc = document.getElementById("container");
                    if (page_html != currentDoc.innerHTML) {
                        var newDoc = document.getElementById("container");
                        newDoc.innerHTML.write(page_html);
                        newDoc.close();

                    }
                });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header_container">
        <div id="header">
            <a href="http://website.com/" target="_blank">
                <img src="logo.png">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <div id="footer_container">
        <div id="footer">
            <a href="http://website.com/" target="_blank">
                <img src="logo.png">
            </a>
            <div id="footer1">
                <i>Copyright &copy; 2013 <a href="http://website.com/" target="_blank"><font color=blue>Website</font></a>.</i>
            </div>
            <div id="footer2">
                <i>All Rights Reserved.</i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Secondary HTML (output.html)

```
    <table id="gradient" summary="">
        <tbody>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data data</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>5f 212y</td><td><div align="left">2</div></td><td>117.88</td><td>1</td><td>117.88</td><td>1</td><td>-1</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>2</td><td>22</td><td>data</td><td>14</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>Tdata</td><td>6</td><td>data</td><td>135.0%</td><td>data</td><td>555.0%</td><td>0.0%</td><td>10.0%</td><td>2</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>&#163;45552.43</td><td></td><td>data</td><td>data</td><tr>
            <tr><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>5f 212y</td><td><div align="left">2</div></td><td>117.88</td><td>1</td><td>117.88</td><td>1</td><td>-1</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>2</td><td>22</td><td>data</td><td>14</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>Tdata</td><td>6</td><td>data</td><td>135.0%</td><td>data</td><td>555.0%</td><td>0.0%</td><td>10.0%</td><td>2</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>&#163;45552.43</td><td></td><td>data</td><td>data</td><tr>
            <tr><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>5f 212y</td><td><div align="left">2</div></td><td>117.88</td><td>1</td><td>117.88</td><td>1</td><td>-1</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>2</td><td>22</td><td>data</td><td>14</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>Tdata</td><td>6</td><td>data</td><td>135.0%</td><td>data</td><td>555.0%</td><td>0.0%</td><td>10.0%</td><td>2</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>&#163;45552.43</td><td></td><td>data</td><td>data</td><tr>
            <tr><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>5f 212y</td><td><div align="left">2</div></td><td>117.88</td><td>1</td><td>117.88</td><td>1</td><td>-1</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>2</td><td>22</td><td>data</td><td>14</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>Tdata</td><td>6</td><td>data</td><td>135.0%</td><td>data</td><td>555.0%</td><td>0.0%</td><td>10.0%</td><td>2</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>&#163;45552.43</td><td></td><td>data</td><td>data</td><tr>
            <tr><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>5f 212y</td><td><div align="left">2</div></td><td>117.88</td><td>1</td><td>117.88</td><td>1</td><td>-1</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>2</td><td>22</td><td>data</td><td>14</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>Tdata</td><td>6</td><td>data</td><td>135.0%</td><td>data</td><td>555.0%</td><td>0.0%</td><td>10.0%</td><td>2</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>&#163;45552.43</td><td></td><td>data</td><td>data</td><tr>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data data</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>5f 212y</td><td><div align="left">2</div></td><td>117.88</td><td>1</td><td>117.88</td><td>1</td><td>-1</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>2</td><td>22</td><td>data</td><td>14</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>Tdata</td><td>6</td><td>data</td><td>135.0%</td><td>data</td><td>555.0%</td><td>0.0%</td><td>10.0%</td><td>2</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>&#163;45552.43</td><td></td><td>data</td><td>data</td><tr>
            <tr><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>5f 212y</td><td><div align="left">2</div></td><td>117.88</td><td>1</td><td>117.88</td><td>1</td><td>-1</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>2</td><td>22</td><td>data</td><td>14</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>Tdata</td><td>6</td><td>data</td><td>135.0%</td><td>data</td><td>555.0%</td><td>0.0%</td><td>10.0%</td><td>2</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>&#163;45552.43</td><td></td><td>data</td><td>data</td><tr>
            <tr><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>5f 212y</td><td><div align="left">2</div></td><td>117.88</td><td>1</td><td>117.88</td><td>1</td><td>-1</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>2</td><td>22</td><td>data</td><td>14</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>Tdata</td><td>6</td><td>data</td><td>135.0%</td><td>data</td><td>555.0%</td><td>0.0%</td><td>10.0%</td><td>2</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>&#163;45552.43</td><td></td><td>data</td><td>data</td><tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

#### CSS

```
body {
    line-height: 1.6em;
    background-color: #0E4216;
    width: 3200px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

#gradient {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

#gradient th {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #FFFFFF url('images/gradhead.png') repeat-x;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#gradient td {
    padding: 8px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #00000;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    background: #57935e url('images/gradback.png') repeat-x;
}

#gradient tfoot tr td {
    background: #e8kkff;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #99c;
}

#gradient tbody tr:hover td {
    background: #d0defd url('images/gradhover.png') repeat-x;
    color: #339;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#header_container {
    background: #0E4216 url('images/gradhead.png') repeat-x;
    border: 0px solid #666;
    height: 80px;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

#header {
    line-height: 60px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 940px;
    text-align: center;
}

#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 80px 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#content {
}

#footer_container {
    background: #0E4216 url('images/gradhead.png') repeat-x;
    border: 0px solid #666;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 95px;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

#footer {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ECECEC;
}

#footer1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 130%;
    top: 50px;
}

#footer2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 110%;
    top: 70px;
}
```

#### Function what makes the original html page

```
def get_html_table(data):
    s = """<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>website data</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
@import url("nstyle.css");
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header_container">
    <div id="header">
        <a href="http://website.com/" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.website.com/logo.png"></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <table id="gradient-style" summary="">
        <tbody>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data data</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>\n"""
    for row in data:
        if not row:
            s += """            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data data data</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>\n"""
        else:
            s += '        <tr>'
            for counter, cell in enumerate(row):
                if counter == 6:
                    s += r'<td><div align="left">{}</div></td>'.format(cell)
                else:
                    s += r'<td>{}</td>'.format(cell)
            s += '<tr>\n'
    s += """        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="footer_container">
    <div id="footer">
        <a href="http://website.com/" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.website.com/logo.png"></a>
        <div id="footer1">
            <i>Copyright &copy; 2013 <a href="http://website.com/" target="_blank"><font color=blue>website</font></a>.</i>
        </div>
        <div id="footer2">
            <i>All Rights Reserved.</i>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>"""
    return s
```

#### `data` variable example:

```
[['data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data'], '', ['data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data']['data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'data']]
```

Obviously the above bit of code can be modified

Anyone have any ideas? Help would be much appreciated.
I'll add a bounty to this in two days so if anyone can fix this I'll award you a bounty when I can set it :)

Comment: why are you creating whole html document in `output.html` that is including `<html>,<meta><head> etc..`.  Instead of this you can create a snippet i.e.  the content of body `<divid ="header_container">....</div> <div id="footer_container">.....</div>`

Comment: Because at first I wasn't going to make it update, however now I need it to update but yeah I can change that so I only have the content of the body.

Comment: @UDB I added some code what I tried based on what I think you were hinting towards... but still not working

Comment: Does data only get append? Or can data from output.html override previously fetched information?

Comment: I think you can make this task even easier if instead of outputting HTML in the second par you output JSON. It would remove the need to parse the HTML inside the second page to extra data.

Comment: @JasonSperske I'm unsure how I can make my original task create the json, I've added the function what generates the html including the list of list (with a blank dataset for a new "segment") any suggestions?

Comment: @JasonSperske just saw your other comment, the data what is in output.html doesn't get data appended instead it gets overwritten, it could be the same data in 99.9% of the cells but a random cell might be different, it could have a row/line removed or an entire column might update with new text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:-

separate the server side script or mechanism you are using to generate html files for the creation of updated new content that is `newoutput.html` from the one you are using to create `output.html`(considering output.html as the page loaded in browser when user visits the page very first time or return back after navigating to other pages on the same domain).Similarly use two different functions one to load whole document that is `output.html` and other which will be called after the interval of 250 Msecs .This will reduce the work load of altering the whole html document as it's only table that is required to be updated after every 250 milliseconds. `output.html` can contain whole document (`<html>..</html>`) but the second script should write snippet of `innerHtml of #container` only (assuming `<div id="container"><table id="gradient" sumary=""></table></div>`), in `newoutput.html`

---

**content of newoutput.html generated by createNewOutput.php: -**

---

```
<table id="gradient" summary="">
    <tbody>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">data</th>
                <th scope="col">data</th>
                <th scope="col">data</th>
                <th scope="col">data data</th>
                <th scope="col">data data</th>
                <th scope="col">data</th>
                <th scope="col">data</th>
                <th scope="col">data</th>
                <th scope="col">data data</th>
                <th scope="col">data</th>
                <th scope="col">data data</th>
                <th scope="col">data</th>
                <th scope="col">data</th>
                <th scope="col">data</th>
                <th scope="col">data</th>
                <th scope="col">data</th>
                <th scope="col">data data data</th>
                <th scope="col">data data</th>
                <th scope="col">data data</th>
                <th scope="col">data</th>
                <th scope="col">data data data</th>
                <th scope="col">data data</th>
                <th scope="col">data data data</th>
                <th scope="col">data</th>
                <th scope="col">data data</th>
                <th scope="col">data data</th>
                <th scope="col">data data</th>
                <th scope="col">data data</th>
                <th scope="col">data data</th>
                <th scope="col">data</th>
                <th scope="col">data</th>
                <th scope="col">data</th>
                <th scope="col">data</th>
                <th scope="col">data data data</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>5f 212y</td><td><div align="left">2</div></td><td>117.88</td><td>1</td><td>117.88</td><td>1</td><td>-1</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>2</td><td>22</td><td>data</td><td>14</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>Tdata</td><td>6</td><td>data</td><td>135.0%</td><td>data</td><td>555.0%</td><td>0.0%</td><td>10.0%</td><td>2</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>&#163;45552.43</td><td></td><td>data</td><td>data</td><tr>
        <tr><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>5f 212y</td><td><div align="left">2</div></td><td>117.88</td><td>1</td><td>117.88</td><td>1</td><td>-1</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>2</td><td>22</td><td>data</td><td>14</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>Tdata</td><td>6</td><td>data</td><td>135.0%</td><td>data</td><td>555.0%</td><td>0.0%</td><td>10.0%</td><td>2</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>&#163;45552.43</td><td></td><td>data</td><td>data</td><tr>
        <tr><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>5f 212y</td><td><div align="left">2</div></td><td>117.88</td><td>1</td><td>117.88</td><td>1</td><td>-1</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>2</td><td>22</td><td>data</td><td>14</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>Tdata</td><td>6</td><td>data</td><td>135.0%</td><td>data</td><td>555.0%</td><td>0.0%</td><td>10.0%</td><td>2</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>&#163;45552.43</td><td></td><td>data</td><td>data</td><tr>
        <tr><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>5f 212y</td><td><div align="left">2</div></td><td>117.88</td><td>1</td><td>117.88</td><td>1</td><td>-1</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>2</td><td>22</td><td>data</td><td>14</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>Tdata</td><td>6</td><td>data</td><td>135.0%</td><td>data</td><td>555.0%</td><td>0.0%</td><td>10.0%</td><td>2</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>&#163;45552.43</td><td></td><td>data</td><td>data</td><tr>
        <tr><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>5f 212y</td><td><div align="left">2</div></td><td>117.88</td><td>1</td><td>117.88</td><td>1</td><td>-1</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>2</td><td>22</td><td>data</td><td>14</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>Tdata</td><td>6</td><td>data</td><td>135.0%</td><td>data</td><td>555.0%</td><td>0.0%</td><td>10.0%</td><td>2</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>&#163;45552.43</td><td></td><td>data</td><td>data</td><tr>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">data</th>
                <th scope="col">data</th>
                <th scope="col">data</th>
                <th scope="col">data data</th>
                <th scope="col">data data</th>
                <th scope="col">data</th>
                <th scope="col">data</th>
                <th scope="col">data</th>
                <th scope="col">data data</th>
                <th scope="col">data</th>
                <th scope="col">data data</th>
                <th scope="col">data</th>
                <th scope="col">data</th>
                <th scope="col">data</th>
                <th scope="col">data</th>
                <th scope="col">data</th>
                <th scope="col">data data data</th>
                <th scope="col">data data</th>
                <th scope="col">data data</th>
                <th scope="col">data</th>
                <th scope="col">data data data</th>
                <th scope="col">data data</th>
                <th scope="col">data data data</th>
                <th scope="col">data</th>
                <th scope="col">data data</th>
                <th scope="col">data data</th>
                <th scope="col">data data</th>
                <th scope="col">data data</th>
                <th scope="col">data data</th>
                <th scope="col">data</th>
                <th scope="col">data</th>
                <th scope="col">data</th>
                <th scope="col">data</th>
                <th scope="col">data data data</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>5f 212y</td><td><div align="left">2</div></td><td>117.88</td><td>1</td><td>117.88</td><td>1</td><td>-1</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>2</td><td>22</td><td>data</td><td>14</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>Tdata</td><td>6</td><td>data</td><td>135.0%</td><td>data</td><td>555.0%</td><td>0.0%</td><td>10.0%</td><td>2</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>&#163;45552.43</td><td></td><td>data</td><td>data</td><tr>
        <tr><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>5f 212y</td><td><div align="left">2</div></td><td>117.88</td><td>1</td><td>117.88</td><td>1</td><td>-1</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>2</td><td>22</td><td>data</td><td>14</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>Tdata</td><td>6</td><td>data</td><td>135.0%</td><td>data</td><td>555.0%</td><td>0.0%</td><td>10.0%</td><td>2</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>&#163;45552.43</td><td></td><td>data</td><td>data</td><tr>
        <tr><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>5f 212y</td><td><div align="left">2</div></td><td>117.88</td><td>1</td><td>117.88</td><td>1</td><td>-1</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>2</td><td>22</td><td>data</td><td>14</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>Tdata</td><td>6</td><td>data</td><td>135.0%</td><td>data</td><td>555.0%</td><td>0.0%</td><td>10.0%</td><td>2</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>&#163;45552.43</td><td></td><td>data</td><td>data</td><tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

then make some changes in your `javascript` code

```
 load_content()  //loads output.html
     $(document).ready(function (e) {
        var refresher = setInterval(function(){update_content();}, 250);
    })

function update_content()
{
  $.ajax({
   url: 'createNewOutput.php',
   success:function(){
   $.get('newoutput.html',function(data)
   {
      if(data!=$('body #container').html())
      {
        $.when( $('body #container').empty().append(data) ).then(

        //if styling is not visible on dynamically added content add css here for example

       #gradient.css({
          font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
          font-size: 12px;
          margin: 0px;
          width: 100%;
          text-align: center;
          border-collapse: collapse;
       });

      //..and so on......
      ) //end of then
      } //end of if
   }) //end of get
  } //end of success
})//end of ajax
}//end of update_content
```

this solution is appropriate if change in whole table is expected but if there are only few elements in which change is expected for example- data in second row of table, you can use server side script to return some limited data from the database in the form of say `json` or simple `text` and then parse that (in case of json) and compare that with the innerHTML of targeted elements.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll try that in a bit. I'm unsure how i can create a script to create the json file because my code what creates the html basically generates it based on a csv file on an update there could be one cell change, entire table changes, lines deleted or entire columns updated. Column 0, 1 and 2 if merged into a string well definitely not change so they can be a unique indentifier (the row/line could be deleted sometimes)

Comment: I'm completely unable to get this working in any way shape or form.

Comment: I'm unsure how I can make my original task create the json, I've added the function what generates the html including the list of list (with a blank dataset for a new "segment") any suggestions?